# Using Marionette and LoDash to populate input value

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, lodash

My goal is to populate my Marionette template when the model changes.

I have a template that is a form:

```
<!-- EditContact.html -->
<fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxLength="64" value="{{name}}">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="{{email}}" />
</fieldset>
```

In my Controller.js, I fetching the model:

```
//this is a Backbone Collection
myContactInfo = new ContactInfo({
    url: this.getInfoUri+'?cId=X342;3&transfer=0',
    cId: cId
});

myContactInfo.fetch({
    success: function(){
        contactInfo = myContactInfo.models[0];
        that.editContactLayout.model = contactInfo;
        console.log(contactInfo);
    }
});
```

I use the same layout for creating records. How do I update the view to automatically populate the fields with the model. Do I have to manually use jquery for each element or can I do it in the view using lodash?

Comment: you want to render template on model change event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for an edit contact action exemple. Following as an example that should work fine.

```
var ContactController = Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({

    editAction: function(contactId) {

        ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: "/contacts"
        });
        var contactCollection = new ContactCollection();

        contactCollection.fetch().done(function(){
            // executed after the contacts from server are retrieved

            // get the specific contactId
            var contact = contactCollection.get(contactId);

            // show model in the edit view
            var editView = new ContactEditView({model: contact});
            applayout.show(editView);
        });

    }

});
```

Marionette views have a property "modelEvents" e "collectionEvents". Those should be used as much as possible as they make your code cleaner.

Check out the docs about them: http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.itemview.html#modelevents-and-collectionevents.